# Copy file before today date from one folder to another using command prompt

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How can I copy all files from the folder except today's files to another folder.
So How can I find files date wise. because I want to those files what are before today. I don't want to copy my today's files.

```
ROBOCOPY C:\xampp\htdocs\a\images C:\xampp\htdocs\a\images1 /MIR
```

I used this command but it copied all files. So please tell me what should I do ahead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation of the robocopy command](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) the parameter `/minage` should do the trick. The number after is the number of days, which you might have to adjust a little to fit your needs:

```
ROBOCOPY /minage:1 C:\xampp\htdocs\a\images C:\xampp\htdocs\a\images1 /MIR
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you brother :)

Comment: If we include for a particular day we need to give /minlad:<n> or /maxlad:<n> where n represents the days or we can give the dateformat as YYYYMMDD